# scala.js with scala.js-react. Is there fetch method?

Tags: ajax, scala, fetch, scala.js

I use `scala.js` with `scala.js-react`. In order to send `ajax` request, I wrote something like:

```
def send(e: ReactEventFromInput) = Callback{
  val v = e.currentTarget.value
  val formData = new FormData()
  formData.append("myVar", v)

  val xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
  xhr.onreadystatechange = (e: org.scalajs.dom.Event) => {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        println("Sended!")
      } else {
        println("Error!")
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.open("POST", "/my-api-route", true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHTTPRequest")
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

It works, but code is terribly long.

Does it provides fetch method like javascript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

**P.S.** Sorry for my English, it's not my native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the `Ajax` object:

```
def send(e: ReactEventFromInput) = Callback{
    val v = e.currentTarget.value
    val formData = new FormData
    formData.append("myVar", v)

    Ajax.post("/my-api-route", formData) map (r =>
      println("Sended!")
    ) onFailure {
      case dom.ext.AjaxException(r) => println("Error:" + r.response)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is the Ajax object? (The import)

Comment: org.scalajs.dom.extensions, unless I'm mistaken,